# Efficiently mapping members to their owning structure

Tags: scala

Lets say I have the class `Family` which has a structure of members of the family inside it, not really relevant for this problem as long as there is a function provided by `Family` called `def member(m : Member) : Boolean` which returns `true` if the member `m` is 'part' of the family.

Most importantly however, a member can be part of multiple families.

I have a separate list of all the Members and wish to create a mapping between member and family for fast lookup.

So I have something like this:

```
val allMembers : Set[Member] = getAllMembers()
val allFamilies : Set[Family] = getAllFamilies()

val memberFamilyMap : Map[Member, Set[Family]] = ???
```

What is the most efficient way to create the above `memberFamilyMap` given the `Family.member` function, and that a member can be a member of multiple families? I am trying to use a for-comprehension with generators of the two, but things got a bit hairy (I am a bit new to Scala)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
 allMembers.map(m => m -> allFamilies.filter(_.member(m))).toMap
```

There might be something more efficient though.